# I can't insert more than 7 columns in php prepare statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

This code works perfect but when when I add one or more column `prepare` return `null` and can't insert in to the database

```
public function createTeacher($teacher_id,$fname,$mname,$lname,$mobile_number,$email,$CGPA,$password,$qualification,$gender)
{
    if($this->isTeacherExist($teacher_id,$mobile_number,$email))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        $password=md5($password); 
        $stmt =$this->con->prepare( "INSERT INTO `tbl_teacher_registration` (`teacher_id`, `fname`, `mname`,`lname`,`mobile_number`,`email`,`password` )VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?);");
        if($stmt===false)
        {
            die('prepare() failed: '.htmlspecialchars($this->con->error));
        }
        else
        {
            $stmt->bind_param("ssssiss",$teacher_id,$fname,$mname,$lname,$mobile_number,$email,$password );
        }
        if($stmt->execute())
        {
            $stmt->close();
            return 1;
        }
        else
        { 
            return 2;
        }
    }
}
```

I spend a day for finding the solution any answer welcomed
thanks for your help! everything work beside adding the new column and I want a new column qualification in the same manner

Comment: Please post the complete set of codes (including the bind_param part, etc. )

Comment: There is no reason a prepared statement will not accept more than 7 input parameters - perhaps if you were to show the table schema and show examples of a statement ( with additional columns and placeholders ) that fails.

Comment: You seem to be confusing rows with columns..

Comment: Please show the code that causes failure. Also `md5` should not be used for hashing, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing, specially not using `MD5()` or `SHA1()`. 
PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them for the safety of your users.

Comment: Are you sure you are passing just numbers for the mobile number you have typed as Integer?

Answer (score 0):

add 1 more ? as a value in it, or if id no is automated then remove it from insert statement

Comment: teacher_id is not autoincrement it just insert for the above query ,but when I add one or more ? and value in it prepare returning false .